# Linear Algebra- Sums of Vector Spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, span

I dont know how to prove this although intuitively I know that it is true:

Let $ V $ be a finite dimensional vector space and $S$ and $T$ be subsets of $ V $.

Show that $$ Sp(S\cup T)  = Sp(S)+Sp(T) $$ I think I have to show both sides are subsets of each other but I'm not sure how. I take it the question means sum of two vector spaces for the RHS

Edit: $Sp(S)=<S>$

Comment: Does :$Sp(S)=<S>$ ?

Comment: Yes $Sp(S)=<S>$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$S\subset \operatorname{Sp(S)}\subset \operatorname{Sp}(S)+\operatorname{Sp}(T),$$
and similarly $\,T\subset\operatorname{Sp}(S)+\operatorname{Sp}(T)$, whence $S\cup T \subset \operatorname{Sp}(S)+\operatorname{Sp}(T)$, and finally (remember the span of a subset is the intersection of all the subspaces which contain that subset):
$$ \operatorname{Sp}(S\cup T) \subset \operatorname{Sp}(S)+\operatorname{Sp}(T).$$

Conversely, as $\,S\subset S\cup T$, $\,\operatorname{Sp}(S)\subset\operatorname{Sp}(S\cup T)$. The same is true for $T$, so that:
$$\operatorname{Sp}(S)+\operatorname{Sp}(T) \subset\operatorname{Sp}(S\cup T).$$

Comment: "remember the span of a subset is the intersection of all the subspaces which contain that subset" - I dont understand this. And how you go on to deduce the next thing

Comment: What is your definition of the span of a subset?

Comment: All linear combinations of that subset

Comment: In that case my parenthetical remark is useless. It's evident that if $S\cup T$ is contained in a subspace, its span is also contained in the subspace. But the characterisation I mentioned is true, and can be the useful point of view in some case. You also can say it is the smallest (for inclusion) subspace that contain $S\cup T$.

Comment: ahhhhh- because each span on the RHS is a subspace and the sum of two subspaces is a subspace?  $ S\cup T $  is contained in a subspace- so its span is contained in that subspace?

Comment: It's exactly that.